# How to get systemd to not override DNS settings for a network interface?

Tags: networking, systemd, dns

I'm trying to set my DNS to 1.1.1.1. I've edited `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` to contain:

```
[Resolve]
DNS=1.1.1.1
FallbackDNS=8.8.8.8
```

But it seems like that setting is being overwritten on a per-interface basis. Output of resolvectl:

```
Global
           Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
    resolv.conf mode: foreign
  Current DNS Server: 1.1.1.1
         DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1
Fallback DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8
          DNS Domain: ~.

Link 2 (enp6s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.0.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1
```

How can I either get enp6s0 to not overwrite the global setting, or just set it to 1.1.1.1?

Comment: is enp6s0 perhaps getting DNS settings via DHCP?

Comment: see [this documentation for systemd.network](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#UseDNS=)

Comment: stop,disable, and mask systemd-resolve, create a static /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: @StephenBoston that does work but I wanted to do things the "right" way.

Comment: @vluzko The "right" way is always the simplest way that meets your requirements. First rule in programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this. I'm also running NetworkManager, and it looks like it was overriding the DNS settings for that interface. Editing the DNS settings in `nmtui` and setting `Ignore automatically obtained DNS parameters` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've run into this:

> Without the Domains=~. option in resolved.conf(5), systemd-resolved might use the per-link DNS servers, if any of them set Domains=~. in the per-link configuration.

[Quoted from Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-resolved#Manually)

This does seem to have happened in your case.

It seems the solution is to add `Domains=~.` to `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`:

```
[Resolve]
DNS=1.1.1.1
FallbackDNS=8.8.8.8
Domains=~.
```

---

The [man page for resolved.conf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolved.conf.5.html) may help explain why this happens:

```
The domains prefixed with "~" are called "route-only
domains". All domains listed here (both search domains and
route-only domains after removing the "~" prefix) define a
search path that preferably directs DNS queries to this
interface. This search path has an effect only when suitable
per-link DNS servers are known. Such servers may be defined
through the DNS= setting (see above) and dynamically at run
time, for example from DHCP leases. If no per-link DNS
servers are known, route-only domains have no effect.

Use the construct "~."  (which is composed from "~" to
indicate a route-only domain and "."  to indicate the DNS
root domain that is the implied suffix of all DNS domains) to
use the DNS servers defined for this link preferably for all
domains.
```

What seems to be happening is that the DHCP server is telling your system to use these DHCP servers for all domains, and your static configuration is *not* doing the same, meaning that it gets overriden.